# Define a css grid that has column width is max of screen width

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a horizontal carousel using grid layout, but I'm getting stuck at defining a grid that has column width full size of screen width.

I have defined a grid using below code, but it didn't work

```
  display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr; grid-auto-flow: column;
```

Comment: If your grid is nested into a container and each column has a parent can't you just set `width: 100%;` Please provide applicable CSS and HTML.

Comment: I wonder why use the grid in the first place if the target is to take the full width?

Comment: @AhmedElbessfy it gives the opporunity to use order , gap, and alignement and gives also BFC ;) but he probably misunderstood how to put everything on a single row with each cells be 100vw of width ;) It's a poor question missing details code + attempts and a clear description of what expected )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use grid-auto-column set at the viewport width.

Each column will then take on that width and there will be as many columns as there are images (elements in the carousel).

Here's a simple demo:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 100vw;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.container div {
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: red;">1</div>
  <div style="background: green;">2</div>
  <div style="background: blue;">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Haworth! just work